# Can not infer type of generic function in recursive enums in Rust

Tags: generics, functional-programming, rust, type-inference, recursive-datastructures

I'm working with recursive enums in Rust. I have the following code:

```
enum Rdd<T, G, H>
where
    G: (Fn(&T) -> H),
{
    Data(Vec<T>),
    Map(G, Box<Rdd<T, G, H>>)
}

fn main() {
    let mut v1: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let rdd_1 = Rdd::Data(v1); // It does not work
}
```

When I try to compile It throws:

```
let rdd_1 = Rdd::Data(v1); // It does not work
^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `G`

consider giving `rdd_1` the explicit type `Rdd<u32, G, H>`, where the type parameter `G` is specified
```

Why should I provide a type for `G` parameter as It's not needed for the `Rdd::Data` enum? How could I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler needs to know all the generic parameters since you could update the value to `Rdd::Map`, and thus it wants to know its size.

In this situation, I would create my own constructor with dummy default generic parameters:

```
enum Rdd<T, G = fn(&T) -> (), H = ()>
where
    G: (Fn(&T) -> H),
{
    Data(Vec<T>),
    Map(G, Box<Rdd<T, G, H>>)
}

impl<T> Rdd<T, fn(&T), ()> { // for example
    fn new_data(data: Vec<T>) -> Self {
        Rdd::Data(data)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v1: Vec<u32> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
    let rdd_1 = Rdd::new_data(v1);
}
```

Note that you cannot update your `rdd_1` with any `Map` you want.

Comment: Thank you soy much! It works. Unfortunatelly as you say, I cannot use any map function, I'll read about GADT in Rust. I don't understand why G is equal to `()` and then you use the `where`, but I will finish the book and I hope the explanation is there. Thank you again

Comment: `new_data` creates an `Rdd` with dummy parameters `G` and `H`: that's why I wrote that this solution is useful only when you won't user the `Map` variant after that.